# Jquery - Why wont my image animate on mouseover?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate

Im trying to get my images to animate on mouse over (hover) but for some reason its not working at all.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $(function() {
            $('img.caption').hover(function(){
                $(this).find('img').animate({top:'182px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
            }, function(){
                $(this).find('img').animate({top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
            });
        });
 });
```

and the adjoining html

```
<div class="imagediv"><img class="caption" src="images/gallery/placeholder.jpg" alt="This is test" title="" /></div>
```

I have another hover even linked back to the caption class, could it be a conflict. When i Mouseover the image nothing happens :/

Would this interfere with the other code?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".caption").hover(
                function () {
                  $("#gallerydescription").html( $(this).attr("alt"));

  }, 
  function () {
    $("#gallerydescription").html("");
  }
);
 });
```

Comment: Why do you have `$(document).ready(function() {` and `$(function() {`? They're equivalent, you only need one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/Hxf6F/)

As I stated in comments:

1. The following are equivalent, pick and choose:

   `$(document).ready(function(){`

   `$(function() {`
2. you can remove the `find` function, as you've already started with the img
3. you can remove the `px` from the assignment
4. you need to give your img a `position` (absolute/relative)

---

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('img.caption').hover(
      function(){ $(this).animate({top:'182'},{queue:false,duration:500}); },
      function(){ $(this).animate({top:'0'},{queue:false,duration:500});   }
   );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `$(document).ready(function(){` is the same as `$(function() {`, basically you're doing the same thing twice, lose one of them.
2. `$('img.caption')` already selects the image, while `$(this).find('img')` will start looking for images inside that image. Nothing will be found.
3. the CSS `position` needs to either be `relative` or `absolute` for your animate to work:

   `img {
         position: relative;
      }`

   ```
   $(function(){
       $('img.caption').hover(
           function(){
               $(this).animate({top:'182px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
           },
           function(){
               $(this).animate({top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
           });
   });
   ```

**EDIT:**

The second `.hover()` shouldn't interfere, as it doesn't seem to do anything with the image itself.

See this fiddle for verification: http://jsfiddle.net/4c6Kx/6/

Your best bet would be to start commenting different blocks of code until you find the culprit.

Comment: hmm yeah, thanks, it seems to work fine on fiddle but not on the page.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the easing script. any known conflicts?

Comment: I have no experience with that, would have to see some relevant code.

Comment: find it very peculiar that we had almost the same answer and that the Google image was used in your JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('img.caption').hover(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                top: '182px'
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 500
            });
        }, function() {
            $(this).animate({
                top: '0px'
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 500
            });
        });
});
```

Then give your image `position:relative`

Comment: hmm ive tried all of the suggestions but still nothing on mouseover.

Comment: could it do with the code ive added on the reedit also using the .caption for a hover?